# How can I find out if a substring exists in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string

I know many questions already asked about this problem, but I was not able to find the right answer for my specific problem.

I have a search string - "1|1"

I have a array containing following values - "a" => "1|1", "b" => "2|1,1|1", "c" => "3|2,2|1"

All I want to do is just to find if the search string existed in the array, it should return the array key. If more than one array item has the search string, it should return all of them.

In this example, I am expecting to get both "a" and "b", but when I use `strpos()`, it only gives me "a".

How can I solve this problem?

Edit**

This is my code

```
function array_search_i($str, $array)
{
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($str, $value) !== false) {
            array_push($returnArray, $key);
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out for the `!==` operator. We have to check for the type as well..

```
$searchArray = array('2|2','1|1,3|3','1|1');
$search = '1|1';
foreach ($searchArray as $k=> $value) {
    if (strpos($value,$search) !== false) {
        $keysWithMatches[] = $k;
    }
}

print_r($keysWithMatches);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for GWW and Freddy K. I have made a mistake by using wrong parameter order in strpos.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [**preg_grep**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
print_r(preg_grep("/1\|1/", $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$keys = array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    if(strpos($v,'1|1') !== false) $keys[] = $k;
}
```

Comment: I did exactly lie this, but im only getting "a", not "b"

Comment: Oh sorry I had a type it should be `strpos($v,'1|1')`

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` will only "Find position of first occurrence of a string ".

Look at `array_keys`.  I think this will be closer to what you want.  Alternatively, if it's not able to do "partial matching" which is what you probably need, you may have to use `array_map` or `array_filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is using the PHP native function [array_key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Here is how it works:

```
$array = array("a" => "1|1", "b" => "2|1,1|1", "c" => "3|2,2|1");

$result = array_keys($array,'1|1');

print_r($result);
// 'a' => '1|1'
```

UPDATE:

```
print_r($array[$result[0]]); // Makes more sense.
                             // '1|1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $array = Array("a" => "1|1", "b" => "2|1,1|1","c" => "3|1,2|1","d" => Array("a1" => "1|1"));
    array_walk($array,"find");

    function find($value, $key) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            if (preg_match("/\b1\|1\b/i",$value)) {
            echo $key .'<br />';
            }
        }
        else {
            array_walk($value,"find");
        }
    }
?>
```

By this example you will get:

```
a
b
a1
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you need. Try the following code.

```
$array = array("a"=>array("1|1"), "b"=>array("2|1","1|1"), "c"=>array("1|2"));
var_dump(array_keys(array_filter($array, function ($elem) { return in_array('1|1', $elem); } )));
```

###OUTPUT

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_keys with search_value parameter to search for all values in an array.

This example will get keys of all matching exact values:

```
<?php
$searchArray = array('2|2','1|1','1|1');
$search = '1|1';
print_r(array_keys($searchArray, $search));
?>
```

(OR)

This example will get the key of all the partial-values

```
<?php
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   if(strpos($val,'green') !== false) {
      $resKeys[] = $key;
   }
}

print_r($resKeys);
?>
```